# Bootstrap select styling

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get an input, select and submit horizontally aligned.

```
<div class="input-append">
  <input class="span2" id="input-large appendedPrependedInput" type="text">
     <select class="input-small selectpicker" title="Record">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>MX</option>
    <option>CName</option>
    </select>

<button class="btn" type="button">Go</button>
</div>
```

problem is the select has a rounded front. Any ideas ?

Comment: Do you mean you wall all the top border to align? or have them all align at the baseline?

Comment: just so its only the front and end that are rounded, everything else is square. Thanks